# VBA RegEx on HTML

Tags: html, regex, vba, excel

I have done some reading up on this, and have learned, obviously, that I should not be using RegEx for HTML.

However, if someone can offer me some insight as to how I might better approach the removal of simple HTML tags (bold, italic, and underline) from a range of cells, I would greatly appreciate it. Right now, my macro keeps returning a runtime error of 1004: "Delete Method of Characters Class Failed."

At this point, I'll take any easy solution to this issue.. any advice?

My code:

```
For Each c1 In textRange.Cells
strInput = UCase(c1.text)
    With objRegEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "<\/?\w.?>"
        If .test(strInput) Then
           Set RegMC = .Execute(strInput)
           For Each RegM In RegMC
               c1.Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Delete
           Next
        End If
    End With
Next c1
```

Comment: I think there's a 256 charter limit on the Characters property, so use Value instead.  Also try working backwards through the matches collection.

Comment: Use `.Substitute` but with a better regex. Something like `</?[bui](?:\s[^>]*)?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that if your cell contains multiple tags, then the last delete will fail if the tag was at the end of the string. Since you modified the string, but didn't re-compute the regex, then the indices might be larger than the updated string.

Why not just use `Replace`?

```
 Replace(c1.text, "</b>", "")
```

And do that for each thing you want to get rid of.

Comment: I knew there was something going on there. Indeed, any time there was an issue like this, it would occur at the end of a string. Replace seems to be a simple and effective way to accomplish the same goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
Function HtmlToText(html As String) As String
    Static el As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Static div As Object

    If div Is Nothing Then
        Set el = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set div = el.createElement("div")
        el.appendChild div
        Debug.Print "created"
    End If
    div.innerHTML = html
    HtmlToText = div.innerText
End Function
```

Needs reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library"